# Is it possible for a computer to act as a usb relay?

Tags: usb

I don't know the exact terminology. I have a usb device that connects to a client. I'd like to see the traffic between the two devices. USB traffic analysers cost a lot of money. So I thought maybe I could connect the usb device to my computer and have another usb cable connect to the client. The computer could then sit in the middle and pass the traffic from the device to the client and vice versa, and record the traffic. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, yes. USB is asymetric, there's a host and a device side.

You didn't say what your devices are, so let's assume they are both black boxes where you can't look inside. (If you can look inside, it gets easier). This means device A acts as USB host, and device B acts as USB device (not sure how that maps to your description of "device" and "client").

So to intercept traffic, you need a computer that acts both as USB host on one port (to allow device B to connect), and as USB device on another port (to allow device A to connect).

A normal PC usually doesn't do that, but there are embedded devices or other computers that do. Often these have USB OTG ("on the go") ports, which can act both as host and device.

Once you've found suitable compter, it's easy to configure e.g. Linux to forward traffic between both, and then snoop via `usbmon`. I'm sure it can also be done using other OS.

There's even ready-made software like USBProxy that does all the heavy lifting e.g. on a Beagle Bone Black.

**Edit**

I don't know a generic name for computers that have both kinds of USB ports, I'd google for "USB host" or "USB OTG" together with other keywords. *Single board computers* are a class of computers that are most likely to have both kinds. The mentioned [Beagle Bone Black](https://beagleboard.org/black) is about 60 €, others will be in a similar price range. Computers with just a single USB port (or a single port connected to an internal hub) like the RaspberryPi won't work, even if USB OTG is supported.

You can read up on USB OTG on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go), the article gives a good overview.

Comment: Yes, I guess what I was calling 'client' is meant to be USB Host. Do you have any idea what those devices that can be plugged into a computer and can act as a usb device are called, or how I might go about finding out more about this?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at "USB Redirector" by Incentives Pro.

http://www.incentivespro.com/

They allow you to emulate a USB device on another computer, and pass traffic between the two via TCP/IP.  You might be able to WireShark the IP traffic.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't think this will be useful to me, as the USB Host (terminology I've picked up from dirkt) cannot be connected to a network of any kind, it only accepts direct USB connection. Thank you for your answer though.